# Remove "star" from svg2rlg with reportlab

Tags: python, plotly

I want to remove this little star, the problem is with the **svg2rlg** library and not with Plotly, I did a little test, follow the small script and the results:.

Result using the svg2rlg library to convert SVG to ReportLab:
[image]

Plotly Result:
[image]

```
import os
import pathlib
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from kaleido.scopes.plotly import PlotlyScope
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def pie():
    scope = PlotlyScope()
    labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
    values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)])

    with open(f"{str(pathlib.Path().absolute())}/test.svg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(scope.transform(fig, format="svg"))

    image = os.path.join(str(pathlib.Path().absolute()), 'test.svg')
    svg = svg2rlg(image)
    renderPDF.drawToFile(svg, "file.pdf")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pie()
```

Was install...

- **plotly==4.9.0**
- **kaleido**
- **pandas**
- **svglib**

Topic open in community: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-do-i-remove-this-star-from-the-legend/43994/2

Comment: Unable to recreate this. Can you share sample to code to recreate?

Comment: Sorry, now edited with code.

Comment: The sample code doesn't run. Syntax error with the `multibar` line and the code is now outside of whatever class it was copied from so the references to `self` need to be removed. You're more likely to get an answer if you include a working Minimal and Reproducible example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) that can we can run.

Comment: I maked adjusts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a issue in official repository of library svglib, i speaking about this problem with a collaborate which detected this bug and start a resolution.

https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/250

[image]

Problem resolved: https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/250

Plotly + svglib + ReportLab = OK!